# Alternative IC for ATMEGA

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, atmega, replacement

I'm looking for an IC to replace the ATMEGA chip in the following circuit.
[image: Circuit diagram]

During operation the MCU applies a voltage to the base of the BJT allowing current to flow through the load. However, when the water tank is full, a positive voltage is sent to an input on the MCU and this signal shuts off the base voltage.

(Yes it is a cheap dehumidifier, but here cheap = 50€ so I'd rather repair it than buy new. The only thing lacking is the MCU. Thanks.)

EDIT:
Following comments to look at comparators, I built this using the LM385. It's working fine, but I wonder what issues it has, inefficiencies, risks etc. Btw the ceramic capacitor values differ slightly from what I actually had available. How should this circuit be improved? Thanks [image]

Comment: A couple of comparators and a latch should do the job

Comment: You can use a attiny85 with 8 pins ... Note that you are lacking some capacitors.

Comment: See just this https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYvGi.png

Comment: What do the two LEDs indicate in the original dehumidifier, and do you want the replicate the same LED indicators in the replacement circuit?

Comment: Why do you want to replace the microcontroller? And note, this circuit won't work as-is. Neither the AVR nor the BJT or LEDs will work at 1.25V supply voltage.

Comment: Do you know the behaviour? Without knowing the conditions (truth table, timing, ...) it will be hard to impossible to replace the MCU resembling the original behaviour.

Comment: @sunra The comment from asdfex notes that the configuration of the [LM317](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/lm317-d.pdf) shown is incorrect. If the position of the 100 Ohm resistor is moved as per http://i.stack.imgur.com/RVrV7.png then that will produce a 5 V supply for the ATmega328 which is within the the allowed Vcc for the ATmega328. Did you reverse engineer the schematic in the question from the dehumidifier?

Comment: Is that a typo, did you mean LM393?  385 is a voltage reference, not a comparator. I assume the ATMEGA's ADC pin was used? Do you know if it was used as a threshold, and if so what voltage and time delay or hysteresis?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes typo again, sorry. should be LM358 op amp not voltage reg. ATMEGA is not used here.